# Is there a way to explore a SQLite DB visually (GUI) via WSL2?

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I run a remote Linux instance for my development environment on Visual Studio Code via WSL2. On the bash terminal, I use sqlite3 to access my SQLite DB.

Is there a way to view my DB in a GUI application and access the DB from Linux instance itself - the way we run VS Code? And not via a Windows application accessing the `\\$wsl\` filesystem.

Comment: I'm new here. Please guide if I need to edit this question for better clarity.

Answer (score 8):

From what I understood you are using Visual Studio Code to access your Linux WSL2 development environment.

I also use WSL, this is the solution that I use:

1- You can use the SQLite by alexcvzz plugin for Visual Studio Code it allows you to check the data contained in the tables and run queries. It is also possible to see the SQL queries that generated each table.

[image: View your SQLite database tables at WSL2 using the SQLite Plugin]

[image: You can also run queries]

Comment: Thanks Steve. I ended up using the SQLite VS Code plugin by alexcvzz for basic interaction with the DB.

Comment: This extension didn't work for me, but [this extension](https://github.com/cweijan/vscode-database-client) did.

Comment: @IsaacPak in my case it didn't work until I installed `sqlite3` in WSL2: `sudo apt install sqlite3`

Comment: Neither of these work for me - anyone else got another solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had no success using GUI SQLite apps installed on Windows with a DB located within WSL2. Same goes for all VS Code extensions that I've tried.

However, I did have success using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser) with [WSLg](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg).

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) for instructions on WSLg and [this](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/issues/2142) for for further information on DB Browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following to install `sqlitebrowser`:

```bash
sudo apt install sqlitebrowser
```

to launch it,

```bash
sqlitebrowser [<database>]
```